# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'f1index'

Tags: python

I get an error from this piece of code.

```
fighter1, fighter2 = random.sample(players, 2)
f1index = (players).index(fighter1)
f2index = (players).index(fighter2)
# ^ finds both fighters index in list
f1strength = strengths.f1index
f2strength = strengths.f2index
# ^ finds fighters strength attributes
```

This is the error I get.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "N:\Files\Computing studies\Battle\Tournament.py", line 94, in <module>
    f1strength = strengths.f1index
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'f1index'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the element at position `f1index`, you have to use the subscript notation, like this

```
f1strength = strengths[f1index]
f2strength = strengths[f2index]
```